# how to get value of input in view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am quite new to CodeIgniter. In my application I have page where user enters his details. I want to get that detail in a variable (Lets say  just Name ) and want to use that variable in one of the controller file.

How to do that ?

Comment: Read the manual, post your form data to an action, then access that form data to get your value out of it.

Comment: actually here in code its something like "form_open('register/add/');?>"

Answer (score 0):

From http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html :

```
$post = $this->input->post();
//on the controller you can access this and will return the array
//of the post data you submitted
```

You can also get them by variable name like:

```
$somedata = $this->input->post('some_data');
```

Make sure your form action is pointing to your controller as well. :)

Comment: Ok lets say I have loaded the data by  $this->load->view('register',$data);  Now how do I get one particular variable out of that form data

Comment: You really have to read the docs and go through the tutorials. It is a whole framework that you should at least learn the basics in order to be able to code in it.

Answer (score 0):

for a form value called "supername"

to use locally inside a method

```
$supername = $this->input->post( 'supername', TRUE ) ;
```

to use in any method in the class use **$this->**

```
$this->supername = $this->input->post( 'supername', TRUE ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
$name= $this->input->post('name');
```

Better start off with some tutorials on Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has this **[Input class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)** wherein simplifies the inputs when they are used in some conditional statements.

To answer your question, on how to fetch the data entered by the user is by:

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
```

Stores the value of ***name*** (it is the name of your field in the form) to a variable name **$name**.

Do you want to know if the field is empty or not?

try:

```
if($name = $this->input->post('name')){
    //$name has the value of the name field and it is not empty, do something.
}else{
    //$name has the value of the name field and it is empty, do something.
}
```

CodeIgniter Input class also has XSS Filtering capabilities, it filters input automatically to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

All you have to do is:

Set it to **TRUE** in your config/config.php

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```